# Can I use parameters from request to create a RequestScope Bean in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm building my first microservice with Spring Boot.

The service connects to an external rest api and I get the credentials for the external api in the request parameters.

I want to create a `RestClient` which can be used for all communications to the external api during a single request to my microservice.

The `RestClient` should then be used in the repository.

I don't know how I can create this `RestClient` and use it in the @Repository.

---

I created a minimalistic version of the microservice for this question:

```
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyController {
    private final MyRepository repository;

    @PostMapping(value = "/data", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public MyData data(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> body) {
        String baseUrl = body.getOrDefault("baseUrl",
                                           "").toString();
        String username = body.getOrDefault("username",
                                            "").toString();
        String password = body.getOrDefault("password",
                                            "").toString();

        return repository.getData();
    }
}
```

```
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyRepository {
    private final RestClient restClient;

    public MyData getData() {
        return restClient
                .get()
                .uri("https://example.com")
                .retrieve()
                .body(MyData.class);
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public RestClient getRestClient() {
        return RestClient.builder()
                .baseUrl("http://example.com/api")
                .defaultHeaders(
                        httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.setBasicAuth("username",
                                                                "password"))
                .build();
    }

//    @Bean
//    @RequestScope
//    public RestClient getRestClientWithParams(String baseUrl, String username, String password) {
//        return RestClient.builder()
//                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
//                .defaultHeaders(
//                        httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.setBasicAuth(username,
//                                                                password))
//                .build();
//    }

}
```

I know there is another point in the combined usage of singleton scoped beans like the @Repository and request scoped beans like the RestClient I want to create.
I moved this out of scope for now, as I read there are options with proxies.

I read that it is possible to create prototype scoped beans with parameters, but those are created each time they are used, so I cannot configure them to be used elsewhere.

I have one working solution, but there I have to pass the credentials all the way down through the methods, messing up the signatures, and then create a new `RestClient` in each repository method.
I don't like this.

And I could create the `RestClient` in the @Controller and create the repository without DI directly in the controller, but then I don't use Spring.

To summarize, I'd prefer to create a @Bean of the `RestClient` for the duration of the request which can then be injected into the repository, so I don't mess up the signature with credentials, but I don't know how I can achieve this.

As I'm totally new to Spring and Spring Boot and also didn't use Java for a long time, I might miss any basic concepts. In this case, I'd be happy about keywords, too.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I got some new insights.

First, there are some ways to achieve this behaviour.
One option is, to create a request scoped bean, inject it in the controller and put all data from the controller into the bean. Then it is accessible where needed.

```
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyController {
    private final RestClientHolder restClientHolder;
    private final MyRepository repository;

    @PostMapping(value = "/data", produces = "application/text")
    @ResponseBody
    public String data(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> body) {
        String baseUrl = body.get("baseUrl").toString();
        String username = body.get("username").toString();
        String password = body.get("password").toString();

        RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .defaultHeaders(httpHeaders -> {
                    httpHeaders.setBasicAuth(username,
                                             password);
                })
                .build();
        restClientHolder.setRestClient(restClient);

        return repository.getData();
    }
}

@RequestScope
@Component
public class RestClientHolder {
    private RestClient restClient;

    public RestClient getRestClient() {
        return restClient;
    }

    public void setRestClient(RestClient restClient) {
        this.restClient = restClient;
    }
}

@Repository
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyRepository {
    private final RestClientHolder restClientHolder;

    public String getData() {
        log.info(restClientHolder.getRestClient().toString());
        return restClientHolder.getRestClient()
                .get()
                .retrieve()
                .body(String.class);
    }
}
```

Another option is, to inject the `HttpServletRequest` into the requestScoped bean and access the data from there.

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Config {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Bean
    @RequestScope
    public RestClient getRestClientWithParams(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        log.info("create RestClient");
        try {
            String bodyText = httpServletRequest.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
            Map<String, Object> body = objectMapper.readValue(bodyText,
                                              Map.class);
            String baseUrl = body.getOrDefault("baseUrl",
                                               "").toString();
            String username = body.getOrDefault("username",
                                                "").toString();
            String password = body.getOrDefault("password",
                                                "").toString();
            return RestClient.builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .defaultHeaders(
                            httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.setBasicAuth(username,
                                                                    password))
                    .build();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

BUT, I also got some advice that it is a bad practice to use request scoped beans and to avoid them whenever possible.

So, in my case I switched the design and created all objects in the controller using Factories, which can be Spring Components and therefore inject all dependencies to the created objects. Just the request scoped dependencies are given to the Factorys' create method.

The final solution looks like:

```
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyController {
    private final MyRestClientFactory restClientFactory;
    private final MyRepositoryFactory repositoryFactory;

    @PostMapping(value = "/data", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public MyData data(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> body) {
        String baseUrl = body.getOrDefault("baseUrl",
                                           "").toString();
        String username = body.getOrDefault("username",
                                            "").toString();
        String password = body.getOrDefault("password",
                                            "").toString();

        RestClient restClient = restClientFactory.create(baseUrl,
                                                         username,
                                                         password);
        MyRepository myRepository = repositoryFactory.create(restClient);

        return myRepository.getData();
    }
}
```

I hope this will be helpful for any future one.